# Problem with updating libcap2 100:2.48-1

Tags: apt, server, updates

Out of nowhere just recently when I tried to update the package (libcap2 100:2.48-1) on my server (Ubuntu 20.04.2) it's refusing to do the update cause a problem with the dependency

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcap2 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.32) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Here is the output of `apt-cache policy libcap2 libc6`

```
libcap2:
  Installed: 1:2.32-1
  Candidate: 100:2.48-1
  Version table:
     100:2.48-1 500
        500 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/kubic:/libcontainers:/stable/xUbuntu_20.10  Packages
 *** 1:2.32-1 500
        500 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libc6:
  Installed: 2.31-0ubuntu9.2
  Candidate: 2.31-0ubuntu9.2
  Version table:
 *** 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 500
        500 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.31-0ubuntu9 500
        500 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

This is all it shows and I am not totally sure about removing libc6 and install it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to disable the `http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/kubic:/libcontainers:/stable/xUbuntu_20.10` repository and then retry.

Comment: should I re-enable it l8r or its nothing important

Comment: also if am not wrong thats a opensuse repo why its there I never added it my self

Comment: I think it is not important, keep it disabled.

Comment: sure will do thanks